# How to make a df with the minimum value of each column and the corresponding value of other column?

Tags: pandas, greatest-n-per-group, min

```
I have a df like this:

        '62'                   '63'               '64'          code
0   20.03743333333333   26.869833333333325  24.724533333333333  82022
1   10.4041             31.236499999999996  29.091200000000004  82026
2   26.88743333333333   33.71983333333333   31.574533333333335  82099
3   19.820766666666664  17.65316666666666   25.507866666666668  82107
4   28.037433333333333  34.86983333333333   32.72453333333334   82193
5   20.754099999999998  27.586499999999994  25.441200000000002  82244
6   31.070766666666664  37.903166666666664  35.75786666666667   82281
7   14.770766666666665  21.603166666666663  19.45786666666667   82332
8   35.53743333333333   42.36983333333333   40.22453333333334   82397
9   41.637433333333334  48.46983333333333   46.324533333333335  82400
```

I want to get the minimum value of each column and their corresponding code in a dataframe, like this:

```
62  10.4041           82026
63  17.65316666666666 82107
64  19.45786666666667 82332
```

I've been trying with:

`df62 = df.groupby(['code'])['62'].min()
df63 = df.groupby(['code'])['63'].min()
df64 = df.groupby(['code'])['64'].min()`

But is not working.

Can you tell me a possible solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
df.set_index('code').agg(['idxmin','min']).T
```

---

```
       idxmin        min
'62'  82026.0  10.404100
'63'  82107.0  17.653167
'64'  82332.0  19.457867
```